# Dropzone with PHP MVC

Tags: javascript, php, dropzone.js

Hy, i have a form with general fields and a php file with a function to get the form filds and persist on mysql, i showd use dropzone to upload some files with these information, but when i press the submit button justo the filds are received on php, the files informations dont

my form code:

```
<form id="myDropzone" class="dropzone form-horizontal" method="POST">

                            <div class="form-group">
                             <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Selecione o associado</label>
                             <select data-placeholder="Selecione o associado" name="idassociado" id="idassociado" class="select2_demo_1 form-control required" style="width:250px;">
                                <option value="">Selecionar</option>
                                <? print_r($home->associados); ?>
                             </select>

                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Marca</label>
                                <div class="col-sm-4"><input type="text" placeholder="Marca do veículo" id="marca" name="marca" class="form-control required"></div>
                                <label class="col-sm-1 control-label">Modelo.</label>
                                <div class="col-sm-2"><input type="text" placeholder="Modelo do veículo" id="modelo" name="modelo" class="form-control required"></div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Placa</label>
                                <div class="col-sm-4"><input type="text" placeholder="Placa do veículo" id="placa" name="placa" data-mask="aaa-9999" class="form-control required"></div>
                                <label class="col-sm-1 control-label">Eixos</label>
                               <div class="col-sm-2"><input type="text" placeholder="Número de eixos" id="eixos" name="eixos" class="form-control required"></div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">

                               <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Ano Fab.</label>
                                <div class="col-sm-2"><input type="text" placeholder="Ano de fabricação" data-mask="9999" id="ano_fab" name="ano_fab" class="form-control required"></div>
                                <label class="col-sm-3 control-label">Ano Modelo</label>
                                <div class="col-sm-2"><input type="text" id="ano_mod" name="ano_mod" placeholder="Ano do Modelo" data-mask="9999" class="form-control required"></div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Cor.</label>
                                <div class="col-sm-3"><input type="text" placeholder="Cor" id="cor" name="cor" class="form-control required"></div>
                                <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Tipo</label>
                                <div class="col-sm-2"> 
                                    <select data-placeholder="Selecione o tipo" name="tipo" id="tipo" class="select2_demo_1 form-control required" style="width:150px;">
                                    <option value="">Selecionar</option>
                                    <option value="Cavalo">Cavalo</option>
                                    <option value="Carreta">Carreta</option>
                                    <option value="Tanque">Tanque</option>
                                    <option value="Truck">Truck</option>
                                    </select>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Quilometragem</label>
                                <div class="col-sm-4"><input type="text" id="quilometragem" name="quilometragem" placeholder="Quilometragem" class="form-control required"></div>

                            </div>

                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Chassi</label>
                                <div class="col-sm-3"><input type="text" id="chassi" name="chassi" placeholder="Chassi" class="form-control required"></div>
                                <label class="col-sm-1 control-label">Renavam</label>
                                <div class="col-sm-3"><input type="text" id="renavam" name="renavam" placeholder="Renavam" class="form-control required"></div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Valor da cobertura</label>
                                <div class="col-sm-2"><input type="text" id="valor_cobertura" name="valor_cobertura" placeholder="Valor da cobertura" class="form-control required"></div>
                                <label class="col-sm-1 control-label">Cotas.</label>
                                <div class="col-sm-1"><input type="text" readonly id="cotas" name="cotas" placeholder="Cotas" class="form-control"></div>
                                <label class="col-sm-1 control-label">Mensalidade</label>
                                <div class="col-sm-2"><input type="text" readonly id="mensalidade" name="mensalidade" Placeholder="Valor da Mensalidade" class="form-control required"></div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Número da ficha:</label>
                                <div class="col-sm-2"><input type="text" id="num_ficha" name="num_ficha" placeholder="Numero da ficha" class="form-control required"></div>
                                <div class="i-checks">
                                    <label> <input type="checkbox" id="rastreador" name="rastreador" value="Sim"> <i></i>Rastreador </label>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                                    <label> <input type="checkbox" id="guincho" name="guincho" value="Sim"> <i></i>Guincho </label></div>                   
                            </div>

                            <div class="form-group">

                                        <div class="ibox-title">
                                            <h5>Fotos do veículo</h5>
                                        </div>
                                            <div name="file" id="file" class="dropzone dz-clickable dz-default dz-file-preview">
                                            </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="form-group">
                                <div class="col-sm-2"></div>
                                <div class="col-sm-4"><button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Cadastrar</button></div>
                            </div>
                    </form>
```

Here is my dropzone code:

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
    $("div#file").dropzone({ url: "#" });

          Dropzone.options.myDropzone = {
                  autoDiscover: false,
                  autoProcessQueue: false,
                  uploadMultiple: true,
                  parallelUploads: 50,
                  maxFiles: 50,
                  paramName: 'pic',
                  addRemoveLinks: true,
                  previewContainer: '#dropzone',
                  clickable: false,

                  accept: function(file, done) {
                    console.log("uploaded");
                    done();

                  },
                 error: function(file, msg){
                    alert(msg);
                  },
                  init: function() {

                      var myDropzone = this;

                     this.element.querySelector("button[type=submit]").addEventListener("click", function(e) {
                        e.preventDefault();
                        e.stopPropagation();
                        myDropzone.processQueue();              
                    });
                  }
         };});
```

And on my model PHP function :

```
public function validate_veiculo_form () {    
        if (!empty($_FILES)) {

                    $tempFile = $_FILES['images']['tmp_name'];               
                        $targetPath = $directory; 
                        $targetFile =  $targetPath. $_FILES['images']['name'];
                        move_uploaded_file($tempFile,$targetFile);


                    }else{

                        $this->error = "Array de fotos vazio";
                        return;
                    }}
```

The only result i get is the "Array de fotos vazio", someone can help me ?